# expectation of squared conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Can we compute
$$
E\big[ E[Y \mid X] \cdot E[Y \mid X] \big]
$$
in closed form?
Supposing that $X$ takes values in $S$ and $Y$ takes values in $T$ (notation from [randomservices.org](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Conditional.html#prp1)), I've tried expanding according to the definitions, but it seems it does not simplify,
$$
E\big[ E[Y \mid X] \cdot E[Y \mid X] \big] = \int_S \bigg(\int_T y P(Y=y \mid X=x)dy \bigg) \cdot \bigg(\int_T z P(Y=z \mid X=x)dz \bigg) P(X=x)dx
$$
Am I missing something?

Comment: Hint: What is $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid X]]$?

Comment: $E[Y]$ but we can only do that once, right? It will be $E[Y \cdot E[Y|X]]$?