# Expectation of the squared conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am considering the expectation of the squared expectation, as asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834192/expectation-of-squared-conditional-expectation) but with no answer and so wanted to get the communities thoughts.

Since $E[Y|X]$ is not independent with itself then the first line of the equation below should be true. I then go on to try to derive the answer using the definitions but would be grateful if someone could point out where I am going wrong.

$$\begin{align}
E[E(Y|X)^2] & \neq E[E(Y|X)] \cdot E[E(Y|X)] \\[10pt]
& = \int_{x \in A_x} E(Y|X)^2 f_{X}(x) dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_{x \in A_x} \Big( \int_{y \in A_y} y f_{Y|X}(y|x) dy \Big)^2 f_{X}(x) dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_{x \in A_x} \int_{y \in A_y} y \ f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_{X}(x) \ dx \ dy \ \Big( \int_{y \in A_y} y \ f_{Y|X}(y|x) \ dy \Big) \\[10pt]
& = \int_{y \in A_y} y \left\{ \int_{x \in A_x} f(y,x)\ dx \right\} \ dy \ \Big( \int_{y \in A_y} y \ f_{Y|X}(y|x) \ dy \Big) \\[10pt]
& = \int_{y \in A_y} y f_{Y}(y) \ dy \ \Big( \int_{y \in A_y} y \ f_{Y|X}(y|x) \ dy \Big) \\[10pt]
& = E[Y] \cdot E[Y|X]
\end{align}$$

In the fourth row I have factored out one of the $E[Y|X]$ expressions and in the fifth row computed the marginal over $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You are going wrong on the fourth line.  You cannot distribute the second conditional expectation outside the scope of the outer integral.  Both are conditioned on the same variable $(x)$.

$\quad\begin{align}\int_\Bbb R\left(\int_\Bbb R y f_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,\mathrm dy\right)^2f_{\small X}(x)\,\mathrm d x &=\int_\Bbb R f_{\small X}(x)\int_\Bbb R yf_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\int_\Bbb R uf_{\small Y\mid X}(u\mid x)\,\mathrm d u\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&= \iint_{\Bbb R^2} y f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\int_\Bbb R uf_{\small Y\mid X}(u\mid x)\,\mathrm d u\,\mathrm d (x,y)\\[2ex] &= \mathbb E(Y\,\mathbb E(Y\mid X))\end{align}$

Comment: Ok understood, thank you. Why have you used $u$ here?

Comment: To distinguish the integrals by substitution, since $\int_A g(y)\mathrm d y=\int_A g(u)\mathrm du$ .